# Django template forloop

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's a excerpt from a Django template:

```
<div id="list-of-things">
    {% for key in things %}
        {% for thing in  thing|get_dict_value:key %}
            <div id="thing-{{ count }}">{{key}}: {{ thing }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`things` is a dict and `get_dict_value:key` is simply `thing[key]`. What's needed in the final page is:

```
<div id="thing-1">A: First thing</div>
<div id="thing-2">A: Second thing</div>
<div id="thing-3">B: Third thing</div>
...
```

...which means that I need some way of altering the `count` variable. Using `forloop.counter` here causes there to be duplicate values as the counter resets for each time through the outer loop.

There doesn't seem to be any way to set a variable in this loop, so is there another means whereby `count` might be incremented as required?

Comment: You want the counter for the parent loop? If yes, check `forloop.parentloop` (*For nested loops, this is the loop surrounding the current one*).

Comment: If only it were that easy - using the parentloop value would also give me duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can do

In the views

```
import itertools
counter = itertools.count()
# pass `counter` to the template
```

In the template

```
{{counter.next}}
```

to display and increment the counter regardless of the loop you're in.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, with a small modification. I had to use `counter` more than once and found that "count(n)" would be printed, but adding a filter to remove non-numeric characters sorted that out.